# IE10 oninput event repeatedly triggered on redirection

Tags: javascript, redirect, dom-events, internet-explorer-10

I've been experiencing an odd problem with IE10 when redirecting the page on an 'oninput' event (with no equivalent issue when using Chrome). I've produced the most pared-down version of the code that still exhibits the problem, as follows:

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onChangeInputText()
{
    window.location.href = "oninput_problem.html"; // Back to this page.
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<input type="text"
    oninput="onChangeInputText()"
    value="£"
    />

</body>

</html>
```

On my Windows 7 PC using IE10, this code when browsed to (either by double clicking or via Apache) repeatedly redirects as if the act of initialising the value of the input text box itself is generating an immediate 'oninput' event. However, when I change the initial input text box value from the '£' symbol to a letter 'A', the repeated redirection doesn't occur.

I first noticed this problem as part of a project I'm working on. In that case, the user's input should cause a delayed page refresh, which began repeatedly redirecting when I entered a '£' symbol. As I say, the above code is the most pared-down version I produced in trying to track what was causing the issue.

Does anyone else experience this using IE10? If so, can anyone explain why IE10 is behaving this way?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the following that appears to indicate that this may be a bug in IE10:

[social.msdn.microsoft.com: Event oninput triggered on page load](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/95e6b9fa-786d-4b32-b457-c891f3744ed3)

Also, there's a follow-up bug report (within the page linked to above):

[connect.microsoft.com: onInput event fires on loading the page when input @value is non-ASCII](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/776510/oninput-event-fires-on-loading-the-page-when-input-value-is-non-ascii#details%20,%20including%20a%20JSfiddle%20of%20the%20issue%3a%20http://jsfiddle.net/Y2tfp/)

EDITED TO ADD: At the bottom of the page pointed to by the second link, there's what would seem to be an unhelpful reply from Microsoft stating that they are unable to reproduce the bug described, so it may be a while before the issue is fixed...

Answer (score 0):

There's anoter bug report which is still open :

[http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/de...](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/816137/ie-11-ie-10-input-elements-with-unicode-entity-character-values-cause-oninput-events-to-be-fired-on-page-load)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might encounter this, you can use this "class" as an alternative to the onInput event.

```
const getFieldWatcherInstance = (function(watchedElement, onElementValueChange){
        let intervalReference = null;
        let lastValue = null;
        if(!watchedElement instanceof Element) return new Error('watchedElement is not an HTML Element');
        if(typeof onElementValueChange !== 'function') return new Error('onElementValueChange is not a function');
        return {
            toggleFieldWatching : function(){
                if(intervalReference){
                    clearInterval(intervalReference);
                    intervalReference = null;
                }
                else{
                    intervalReference = setInterval(function(){
                        const currentValue = watchedElement.value;
                        if(lastValue !== currentValue){
                            onElementValueChange(currentValue);
                            lastValue = currentValue;
                        }    
                    }, 100);   
                }    
            }
        };    
    });
```

Set it up like this:

```
const myInputChangeWatcher = getFieldWatcherInstance(<**insert real element reference here**>, function(newValue){
console.log('The new value is: ' + newValue);
});
```

call myInputChangeWatcher.toggleFieldWatching() in the onfocus and onblur events of the input